# Como colocar um botão "leia mais" "leia menos" em um foreach php?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, laravel

Olá, eu tenho um array dentro de um foreach que traz uma lista de procedimentos. Porém eu quero que apareça apenas os 3 primeiros e tenha um link "leia mais" "leia menos" pra mostrar o restante do conteúdo ou esconder esse conteúdo.

Quando é em uma string, meu javascript funciona. Vou mostrar.

```js
    function AddReadMore() {
        //This limit you can set after how much characters you want to show Read More.
        var carLmt = 350;
        // Text to show when text is collapsed
        var readMoreTxt = " ... Leia mais";
        // Text to show when text is expanded
        var readLessTxt = " Leia menos";
 
 
        //Traverse all selectors with this class and manupulate HTML part to show Read More
        $(".addReadMore").each(function() {
            if ($(this).find(".firstSec").length)
                return;
 
            var allstr = $(this).text();
            if (allstr.length > carLmt) {
                var firstSet = allstr.substring(0, carLmt);
                var secdHalf = allstr.substring(carLmt, allstr.length);
                var strtoadd = firstSet + "<span class='SecSec'>" + secdHalf + "</span><span class='readMore'  title='Click to Show More'>" + readMoreTxt + "</span><span class='readLess' title='Click to Show Less'>" + readLessTxt + "</span>";
                $(this).html(strtoadd);
            }
 
        });
        //Read More and Read Less Click Event binding
        $(document).on("click", ".readMore,.readLess", function() {
            $(this).closest(".addReadMore").toggleClass("showlesscontent showmorecontent");
        });
    }
    $(function() {
        //Calling function after Page Load
        AddReadMore();
    });
```

```css
    .addReadMore.showlesscontent .SecSec,
    .addReadMore.showlesscontent .readLess {
        display: none;
    }
 
    .addReadMore.showmorecontent .readMore {
        display: none;
    }
 
    .addReadMore .readMore,
    .addReadMore .readLess {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 2px;
        color: #00CFA0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
 
    .addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .SecSec,
    .addReadMoreWrapTxt.showmorecontent .readLess {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="addReadMore showlesscontent">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

Ele até funciona desse jeito, só que transforma tudo numa string única. O que eu quero é que mostre os 3 primeiros e quando eu clicar em "leia mais" apareça o restante, só que continuando uma lista.
Vou mostrar o trecho do código:

```html
<span style="" class="addReadMore showlesscontent">
<br>
@foreach($profissional['procedimentos'] as $procedimento)
  <p class="first">{{ strtolower($procedimento['tipo']) }}</p>
@endforeach
</span>
```

A lista é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que o leia menos?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa fazer um resumo completo tem essa função que pode te ajudar:

```
function resumo($string, $chars) {
    if (strlen($string) > $chars)
        return substr($string, 0, $chars).'...';
    else
        return $string;
}

echo resumo("abcde", 4);
```

Depois no botão leia mais se for usar da forma na mesma página você precisa ter a quantidade máxima do strlen e passar para uma ação desse botão "leia mais..." ou redirecionar para outra página com texto completo.